# libgdx setup ui jar file not executing

Tags: java, libgdx, installation

I double click, nothing happens.

I opened cmd from the foler, did:
`java gdx-setup-ui.jar`
and I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class gdx-setup-ui.jar
```

I just updated the JRE recently, to 1.7.0_45, and JDK is 1.6.0_18

I used to create libgdx projects before also, and it used to work. 
I'm using Windows Vista.

Comment: Okay! I uninstalled and reinstalled the whole Java system, and it's working now!
To moderators: you can close this question now.

Answer (score 6):

It should work by just double clicking, though I also noticed that it's buggy sometimes in Windows.

Use `java -jar gdx-setup-ui.jar` (with *-jar*) to execute it manually.

Comment: With `-jar` as well? Which error did you get? I just tried it myself and got your error when I didn't add the `-jar`. But with `-jar` it worked.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry! With `-jar` it's spitting this out:
http://www.pastebin.ca/2485333

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the JRE to open .jar file.
Here is the link http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001343.htm